# Powershell keeps sending key

Tags: powershell

Hi I recently made this script that presses a key in powershell:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

Now I wonder if I can make the script so: The current script above presses the key one time (virtual), I want it to keep the key mentiont pressed (virtual) until I tell the script to let go the key (virtual)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: is it better now @gvee

Comment: I can not understand your question, you want to have a loop until the Enter key is pressed and then do something else?
You need to tell us what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: Is it better now @StefTheo

Comment: So you want to get a loop like:
Do { code } Until { Condition = True }

this will make your code run until a certain condition becomes true.
Is this something you need?

Comment: @StefTheo Yes, but the code presses a key once, and when I put it in a loop, it spams the command. I just want the same effect as you would manualy hold a key

Comment: But how the code is going to know that you want to stop it?
You must have a condition that when it is true the code will stop, exit from the loop and do something else. 
Some examples get-date -displayhint time -lessthan 12:30:00
I just can not understand when you want your code to stop running.
If you can describe the command and what you want to achieve with your script maybe we could help you with that.

Comment: @StefTheo I want to do it with while `(condition == true):` but if I just put the command in there, its gonna spam the command, I want it to send it ones, and keep it active (the key)